# Validate form field after user leaves the field

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, forms, onfocusout

I want to validate a form field after user has left the field. I wrote my html as below

```
 <input type="text" onfocusout="validateIp()"formControlName="ip_address" (input)="onIpChange($event.target.value)" pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9.]*$"class="form-control form-control-sm" id="IP_Address">
```

Below is my typescript code

```
 validateIp(){
    
    console.log('validateIp is called');
  }
```

onfocusout  is not working as expected . Below is error I am getting

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: validateIp is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.onfocusout
```

I have tried onblur also but event is not getting triggered

Comment: `on*` attributes should be changed to their parentheses variant (for e.g. `onfocusout` should be `(focusout)`).

Answer (score 2):

when use ReactiveForms, you can validate onBlur

```
this.form=new FormGroup({
  ip_address:new FormControl(null,{validators: Validators.required,
                                  updateOn: 'blur'})
})
```

Or using formBuilder

```
this.form = this.fb.group({
    ip_address: ["", { validators: [Validators.required], updateOn: "blur" }],
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are inside an Angular component and that you are trying to call a method of this component.

Given that `onIpChange` is defined in the same component as `validateIp`, you have to change your HTML code from

```
<input type="text" onfocusout="validateIp()" formControlName="ip_address" (input)="onIpChange($event.target.value)" pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9.]*$"class="form-control form-control-sm" id="IP_Address">
```

to

```
<input type="text" (focusout)="validateIp()" formControlName="ip_address" (input)="onIpChange($event.target.value)" pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9.]*$" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="IP_Address">
```

Comment: you are using formControl and pattern and input !!!, If you are using ReactiveForms, the validators should been created when create the FormControl